# SharePoint 2010 Lookup Column Display issue

Tags: 2010, list, lookup-column

I have a simple list with three lookup columns in it. One LC has 5 items and displays as simple dropdown and there are no rendering issues (So ignore this column now). The other two columns has more than 20 items and they rendered properly on New and Edit forms but my problem occurs while selecting the dropdowns. Whatever the dropdown i select first, it displays the values for that dropdown but when i select the second dropdown, it displays the second dropdown values but the postion of this dropdown displays on the first dropdown. In case if i refresh the page and i select the second drop down, i see the values and position on second dropdown only but for the first dropdown, i see the first dropdown values and its position on second dropdown. Please help me to fix this[image]

Comment: What method did you use for creating these Lookup Fields? if code please share as to help with the understanding/replication of your issue

Comment: I did not have any code for the lookup-columns. I created the lookup-columns as site columns and then added to the list. Please look at the image to get the clear picture.

Comment: Yet it works fine in Firefox or Chrome... But I think this update fixes the issue, not tested but it is mentioned.. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2598273

Comment: It works for Firefox and Chrome because the 'advanced' (and at the same time broken) rendering of the field is only available for IE5.5+ Does anyone know if this has been fixed in any service pack or hotfix? It is quite critical and disabling the functionality is not the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed these drop downs to simple drop downs using Jquery since i did not find any other way to solve this issue. I followed the following post to convert to simple drop down.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11416099/sharepoint-drop-down-list-doesnt-display-properly-for-more-than-20-items-with-i

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to add that the problem seems to happen in a Microsoft update between Service Pack 1 and December 2012 CU.

More specifically, we tested the following:

1. Fresh installation of SP2010 and the lookups work correctly
2. Update to SP1 and the lookups work correctly
3. Update with December 2012 cummulative update and the behavior is as described by the original poster
4. Update to the latest version today and the problem remains

I have no idea how this can go unnoticed and disabling the functionality is just not a workable solution when the lookup references a list or library with 1000+ items. It is impossible to select something from the rendered list and performance wide it really sucks

Answer (score 0):

This is known bug. Resolution:

To resolve this issue, apply the following hotfix package:

[2687339](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2687339) Description of the SharePoint Foundation 2010 hotfix package (Wss-x-none.msp): August 28, 2012

After you apply the hotfix package, you must create the following flag in the NewForm.aspx page and in the EditForm.aspx page by using SharePoint Designer:

```
<UseStandardControl xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/ListForm">true</UseStandardControl>
```

Or

After you apply the hotfix package, using SharePoint Designer, you may update the web part properties on the List View web part on NewForm.aspx and EditForm.aspx. To resolve the issue, look under miscellaneous and select the "UseStandardControl" check box for both web parts.

More details: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2687375